# Is there any GetJar Testing API Key?

Tags: android

I plan to use GetJar Rewards program in my Android Application. I've downloaded the Rewards SDK and followed the Implementation quick start documentation. This went without any difficulties.

Although, when I'm testing the implementation, I get an `IllegalArgument : invalid UUID` message, obviously because I did not specify my private API key. So my question is : is there some test mode that you can activate with a special test key ? (There is such thing in most of the similar API I've evaluated, ie. Admob, Scoreloop, Flurry, and so on...)

If not, I will just have to wait for the GetJar people coming back on monday (those guys don't work on weekends...)

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I can close this question.
I had to wait some days later, and even if the process was fuzzy, I finally had my key.